# Update an integer field in a kv file depending on a condition

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy

I want to adjust the width of a widget in kv file only in certain cases. For instance:

```
...
width: dp(30) if variable_x else TODO
```

I'm having trouble with the else clause. How can I declare 'do nothing' in case the variable x is not True? 
If I use self.width I run into an infinite loop. I tried also to set None, but it is obviously not allowed for width.

Is there a way to accomplish that in a kv file or should I do it within the python file? Maybe use dynamic classes in kv file for this? What would be the best practice here?

Comment: Well, what width *do* you want it do be when variable_x is not truthy?

Comment: @inclement I want to leave the value unchanged.

Comment: Yes, but unchanged *from what*?

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: If the variable is not true, then do basically nothing. That is what I want to express. Or in other words, change self.width only in case variable_x is True.

I tried the following two statements but neither doesn't work:
1. `width: dp(30) if variable_x else self.width`
2. `width: dp(30) if variable_x else None`
The first statement causes an infinite loop, the second fails due to a type error. Both errors are understandable for me. I hope it is now clear what I want to accomplish.

Comment: It is not clear at all. What value should it take when variable_x is not truthy? 100 pixels? 1000 miles?

Comment: Maybe you want to do the opposite thing, add `on_variable_x: do_your_thing()` where do_your_thing includes a check if variable_x is True. Note that variable_x must be a kivy property for this to work. What you are currently trying makes no sense - the `width: ` line *must* return a number that will be the value of the width property, so if this is to work then you must explain what number you actually want it to have.

Comment: And again, give a code example.

Comment: I think the hint with *on_variable_x: do_your_thing()* is the way to go for me. Thanks for your help.